# Gradient along unique segment/path/line in ggplot by group/y interaction

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, visualization

I would like to visualise a colour gradient along line segments in ggplot2 using a unique start end value to determine the gradient.

For example in the below plot I would like to merge the coloured points with the grey points using a gradient based on the unique position dodge ID and x axis units.

[image]

The code to reach the present plot is as follows:

```
ggplot(percDF) +
  geom_point( aes(x = LME_NAME, y = Value, colour = ID,group = ID ),  position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('#3F3770FF','#3C5397FF','#3573A1FF','#D6456CFF','#F4685CFF','#FEB37BFF')) +
  new_scale_color() +
  
  geom_line(aes( x = LME_NAME, y = Value, colour = ID, group = interaction(LME_NAME, ID)),position = position_dodge(width = 1)  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('#3F3770FF','#3C5397FF','#3573A1FF','#D6456CFF','#F4685CFF','#FEB37BFF')) +
  
  geom_point(data = percDF[percDF$Group == 'BasePercentageSuitable',], aes(x = LME_NAME, y = Value, group = ID ), colour = 'grey' ,position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +

  theme_classic() +
  facet_grid(vars(Reg2), scale = 'free', space='free')
```

I tried adding a 'Z' feature to add an alpha line per unit but this failed. This is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Here is some sample data:

```
LME_NAME              ID Reg2                  Group    Value       Z
Red Sea 2086-2095ssp585  IND     PercentageSuitable 98.58044 98.58044
Red Sea 2086-2095ssp370  IND     PercentageSuitable 98.10726 98.10726
Red Sea 2046-2055ssp126  IND BasePercentageSuitable 97.63407 97.63407
Red Sea 2046-2055ssp370  IND BasePercentageSuitable 97.63407 97.63407
Red Sea 2046-2055ssp585  IND BasePercentageSuitable 97.63407 97.63407
Red Sea 2086-2095ssp126  IND BasePercentageSuitable 97.63407 97.63407
```

Structure:

```
structure(list(LME_NAME = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Red Sea", 
"Pacific Central-American Coastal"), class = "factor"), ID = c("2086-2095ssp585", 
"2086-2095ssp370", "2046-2055ssp126", "2046-2055ssp370", "2046-2055ssp585", 
"2086-2095ssp126", "2086-2095ssp370", "2086-2095ssp585", "2046-2055ssp126", 
"2046-2055ssp370", "2046-2055ssp585", "2086-2095ssp126", "2046-2055ssp126", 
"2046-2055ssp370", "2046-2055ssp585", "2086-2095ssp126", "2086-2095ssp370", 
"2086-2095ssp585", "2086-2095ssp126", "2046-2055ssp126"), Reg2 = c("IND", 
"IND", "IND", "IND", "IND", "IND", "IND", "IND", "IND", "IND", 
"IND", "IND", "PAC", "PAC", "PAC", "PAC", "PAC", "PAC", "PAC", 
"PAC"), Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("PercentageSuitable", 
"BasePercentageSuitable"), class = "factor"), Value = c(98.5804416403786, 
98.1072555205047, 97.6340694006309, 97.6340694006309, 97.6340694006309, 
97.6340694006309, 97.6340694006309, 97.6340694006309, 97.3984109102049, 
97.3984109102049, 97.3984109102049, 97.3984109102049, 89.7893832033944, 
89.7893832033944, 89.7893832033944, 89.7893832033944, 89.7893832033944, 
89.7893832033944, 87.5578863167051, 87.2110007775651), Z = c(98.5804416403786, 
98.1072555205047, 97.6340694006309, 97.6340694006309, 97.6340694006309, 
97.6340694006309, 97.6340694006309, 97.6340694006309, 97.3984109102049, 
97.3984109102049, 97.3984109102049, 97.3984109102049, 89.7893832033944, 
89.7893832033944, 89.7893832033944, 89.7893832033944, 89.7893832033944, 
89.7893832033944, 87.5578863167051, 87.2110007775651)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Does anyone have any ideas for this?

Comment: `ggforce::geom_link` https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_link.html

Comment: For the sample data, what is the starting x value for the values in this group? It seems for this data that Z = Value.  Here's a start, but I couldn't understand what else is necessary for your output.  `ggplot(percDF, aes(x = 85, xend = Value, 
  y = interaction(ID,Group), yend = interaction(ID,Group))) +
  ggforce::geom_link(size = 2, color = "gray70") +
  ggforce::geom_link(size = 2, aes(color = interaction(ID,Group), alpha = after_stat(index))) +
  facet_grid(Reg2~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y")`

Comment: It will be easier for people to help if you can make this more of a minimal example. You have faceting, coord_flip (no longer needed since v3.3 in 2020), LME, ID, "Group" that is used but not explained how, customized theming, etc. and it's not clear to me which of those (if any) are essential to your question.

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't realise geom_link existed! Its not exactly formatted for the xend/yend option so I have used ``geom_link2`` and it works! Can use it to add an alpha grey by index on top of my lines.  ``geom_link2(aes(x = LME_NAME,  y = Value, group = interaction(LME_NAME, ID), alpha = stat(index)), colour = 'grey',  position = position_dodge(width = 1))``

Comment: Sorry, I will make the question more minimal to help, should have done that initially.. apologies.